# Get all related objects with filter on through model

Tags: python, django, graphql, graphene-python

I have the next database structure:

```py
class Artwork():
    id = models.IntegerField(_('id'), primary_key=True)
    artists = models.ManyToManyField('gql_service.Artist',
                                     through='gql_service.ArtistArtwork')

class ArtistArtwork(models.Model): 
    artist = models.ForeignKey('gql_service.Artist')
    artwork = models.ForeignKey('gql_service.Artwork')
    is_main_artist = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Artist(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(_('id'), primary_key=True)
```

`is_main_artist` feature flag used to define is this artist main for this artwork.
In `ArtworkNode` I want to define `main_artist` field:

```py
class ArtworkNode(PrimaryKeyMixin, DjangoObjectType):
    main_artist = graphene.Field('escher.gql_service.schema.artist_node.ArtistNode')
    def resolve_main_artist(self, _):
        return ArtworkInfo(self).main_artist
```

And then in the `ArtworkService` I can access artwork artists like:

```py
class ArtworkInfo(object):
    @property
    def main_artist(self):
        artist = self.artwork.artists.first()

        return artist
```

Is there any way I can filter artists on `ArtworkInfo` and get only one main artist or access values in `ArtistArtwork` model?

Answer (score 1):

You can use related name:

```
class ArtistArtwork(models.Model): 
    ...
    artwork = models.ForeignKey('gql_service.Artwork', related_name='artwork_artistartwork')
```

And then in the `ArtworkService`

```
class ArtworkInfo(object):
    @property
    def main_artist(self):
        artist = self.artwork.objects.filter(artwork_artistartwork__is_main_artist=True).first()
        return artist
```

Answer (score 0):

Did it as:

```py
    @property
    def main_artist(self):
        return self.artwork.artists.filter(
            artistartwork__is_main_artist=True
        ).first()
```

Comment: does this work? I think you should add _set for reverse lookup right?

Comment: ok. I got it. Its because of through parameter.

Comment: With set it returns error "Cannot resolve keyword 'artistartwork_set' into field. Choices are: artistartwork, ..."

Comment: ok. Got it. _set is not useful for reverse lookups when through is used.